# SQL how to format time?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT now()
```

it returns the date and time in format: `YYYY-MMM-DD HH:MM:SS` for example: `2013-01-20 21:26:36`

I'm using this value as part of a file name, the problem is that the char ':' is not allowed.
how can I change the time format to something without `':'`?
for example: `YYYY-MMM-DD HHMMSS`
I've read a lot about the subject and i couldn't find any form of date and time without the `':'`, i found with AM/PM.. or different date formats.. but time is always `':'`.

Comment: Which SQL dialect is this?

Comment: Try a simple google search, you'll find lots of answers.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko looking at your questions , you could have also look for them in google.....The least you can do is to refer him to a duplicate question if theres any.

Comment: What language are you using besides SQL to write the file?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, every question I have asked on here I have googled prior to asking. The OP clearly didn't or they would already have the answer.

Comment: hello ash, i did google before i asked. i am more than willing to send you all the links to sites i visited so that you can see for yourself that the answer wasn't there.

Comment: @ronnjack, if you googled `mysql how to format datetime` then the first link would have given you all the information you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d %H%i%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MySQL just use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H%i%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, this should work.

```
select REPLACE(getdate(),':','-');
```